# nodejs mysql query identifier '?' error, but concatenate query work

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, function, parameters

I am trying to make general queries on my site, I have been handling data with params during my project all this time and without any problem, now with these tables it does not work for me if I do it in the following way:

in the browser: `"localhost:3000/user/2/table/users/list "`

```
router.get('/user/:userid/table/:Tablename/list', function(){
  var table = req.params.Tablename;

  db.get().query('SELECT * FROM  ? ',[table] ,function(err, rows, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    done(rows);
  });

});
```

and this generates an error:

***ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ' 'users' ' at line
1***

---

*but it works if I do this:*

---

```
db.get().query('SELECT * FROM  '+table ,function(err, rows, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
        done(rows);
      });
```

I do not understand why this happens, but I do not want to leave it that way either, I feel that it is not right to leave it that way, besides, is there any inconvenience in leaving it that way?

Answer (score 1):

A friend just shared me why, in the same mysql guide is explained, we must use double character as a marker.

use `??` for identifiers and `?` for values

As explained in the documentation, this would be an example

query : `"SELECT * FROM ?? WHERE ?? = ?"`

I hope that my ignorance and my own response will help someone in a future hehe.

Comment: Warning: it is unsafe to accept a table name as a parameter from the client `req.params.Tablename` and use it this way.  You are setting yourself up for security exploits, allowing unexpected tables to be read.  At the absolute minimum, you need to verify that this table is in a list of acceptable table names for this method. Using `??` is *somewhat less unsafe* than string concatenation (which is extremely dangerous and should never be done under any circumstances) but it is a rule with no exceptions that *nothing* from request parameters can be trusted not to be malicious.